# Geometric rotations of a group of objects

Tags: javascript, geometry

Referring to the first diagram, I am trying to copy the three objects, looking at them from an arbitrary angle(A1). The distance between where I'm and the first object does not matter just the relative location of the object to one another.

In the second diagram, I select a point to copy these objects, facing another arbitrary angle(B1). 
Angle (C1) shows the approximate position of -90 degrees.

I can get this to work if A1 = 0,90,180,270 and even 45,135 etc but the equations I come up with only work for 0 and 180 or 90 and 270. I have to modify them to work in those directions by changing a hardcoded offset angle and putting/removing a negative sign before the offset.

I'm doing this is javascript (and its Minecraft) usually I can figure out this but I have been working on it for weeks.

Here is some **pseudo-code** that works some of the time in certain right-angle directions. I have updated this to be more accurate, the 1x and 2x are the blocks x coordinate, etc. - everything is relative from the (1) block. 
Minecraft's coordinate system is a little different from normal - 0 is south, +90 is west, 180 is north, 270 is east. 
**the only difference is that I am making negative az, ax.**

```
// works for north/south looking - A1 is either 180/0 , B1 can be anything
var x = 1x - 2x;
var z = 1z - 2z;
var direction = Math.atan2(z1, x1);
var L1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(z1, 2));
var az = Math.round(L1 * Math.sin((B1 + A1 + (direction * 180 / Math.PI)) * Math.PI / 180));
var ax = Math.round(L1 * Math.cos((B1 + A1 + (direction * 180 / Math.PI)) * Math.PI / 180));

// works for east/west looking - A1 is either 90/270 , B1 can be anything
var x = 1x - 2x;
var z = 1z - 2z;
var direction = Math.atan2(z1, x1);
var L1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(z1, 2));
var az = -Math.round(L1 * Math.sin((B1 + A1 + (direction * 180 / Math.PI)) * Math.PI / 180));
var ax = -Math.round(L1 * Math.cos((B1 + A1 + (direction * 180 / Math.PI)) * Math.PI / 180));
```

[First diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5fKJ.png)

[image]

[Second diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1wp.png)

[image]

Comment: This is an the correct answer I got on Math stack exchange. thanks
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698475/geometric-rotations-of-a-group-of-objects